# GWT: Native method using JSNI: how to call methods dynamically

Tags: java, gwt, native, jsni

I am using GWT and I have created a native method that calls the method cmd_addspace in the class EverlinkedActions and it works fine for now:

```
private static native String execute(String functionName,  Object[] vParams)/*-{
  try{          
      @es.gwt.client.dash.actions.impl.EverlinkedActions::cmd_addspace([Ljava/lanG/Object;)(vParams);          
  }catch(e){
      alert(e.message);
  }

}-*/;
```

How can i make the method name dynamic? it means instead of "cmd_addspace" i want to call the method "functionName" which its name is passed as argument in the native method.

And is their a way to make the class name also dynamic? i want to have something like that:

```
private static native String execute(String className, String functionName,  Object[] vParams)/*-{
  try{          
      @es.gwt.client.dash.actions.impl.className::functionName([Ljava/lanG/Object;)(vParams);          
  }catch(e){
      alert(e.message);
  }

}-*/;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: did you want to call a Java function or JavaScript method? If Java, you could call a generic method in Java, pass in the name and use reflection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tried it but i was obtaing this error: java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be called in client side

Comment: Oh, I forgot GWT doesn't implement Reflection.

Comment: Sounds like the OP is trying to implement Reflection him/herself!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you're trying to actually achieve here but I'm afraid JSNI doesn't work like that.

Code such as `@es.gwt.client.dash.actions.impl.EverlinkedActions::cmd_addspace([Ljava/lanG/Object;)(vParams);` needs to be a fully resolvable symbol at compile time because class and method names get replaced with their minimised versions.